# Heroku Failing to launch, at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" | django

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

[image: Error I got]

```
2022-02-09T19:08:45.822951+00:00 app[web.1]:     def _real_close(self, _ss=_socket.socket):

2022-02-09T19:08:45.822957+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld

2022-02-09T19:08:45.823031+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()

2022-02-09T19:08:45.823033+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers

2022-02-09T19:08:45.823147+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

2022-02-09T19:08:45.823167+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

2022-02-09T19:08:45.982051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2022-02-09T19:08:46.051992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2022-02-09T19:08:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2022-02-09T19:09:15.623858+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gettaxpass.herokuapp.com request_id=27fc5a09-2b6f-44be-bcc1-3c757d6cabed fwd="43.252.32.40" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is the message I see in my logs.

The code in my log file is also accurate as it is supposed to be.
[image]

Also I have gunicorn installed in my VENV.

Can someone help me deply this django app on heroku.

Django app error:

```
File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\_init_.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\Desktop\taxpass_new\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shreya Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1047, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in _sanity_check
ValueError: Empty module name
```

Comment: please add full error log. It would be better if you can add your Django error log.

Comment: Added the logs in the question, please review it

Comment: My Django app is running on my local server, the problem is with deployment

Comment: don't use any screenshot or picture. We need to be see your full error code.

Comment: okay, Just adding it

Comment: Added the error log of django app and heroku

Comment: You are using an model `module = import_module(entry)` which throwing `ValueError: Empty module name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241879/discussion-between-harsh-kothari-and-boyenec).